# How to let user specify pdf location using iText?

Tags: pdf, netbeans, itext, itextpdf

I made a program that would generate reports. The user is then allowed to save that report in a pdf file format. I want to know if there's a way of letting the user specify which location to save that file.

I am using iText on Netbeans. Thank you :)

Comment: If you are serving up from the web you can't specify a directory.  Mainly due to security and the fact that the server has no idea what file system/structure the user has.

Comment: Is your program running on the user's machine? Or is it a client-server architecture?

Comment: The question is not clear. We really need an answer to the counter-questions asked in the comments.

Comment: It is just running locally, not on web. Sorry if my question is not clear for you